# Does "npm install X --save" means that N will be automatically installed with X if X depends on N?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

Assume that we use npm package `x`, which depends on `n`.
Can we be sure that below code will work even we had not run `npm install n` explicitly?

```js
import { someFunction } from "n";

someFunction();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

According to [npm docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/specifying-dependencies-and-devdependencies-in-a-package-json-file), if a package `X` has a package `N` listed as `dependency` and not as `devDependency` it will be downloaded too.

> To specify the packages your project depends on, you must list them as `"dependencies"` or `"devDependencies"` in your package's `package.json` file. When you (or another user) run `npm install`, npm will download dependencies and devDependencies that are listed in `package.json`

> `"dependencies"`: Packages required by your application in production.

> `"devDependencies"`: Packages that are only needed for local development and testing.

Just pay attention that usually npm libraries are listed in their `dependencies` the minimum required version of other packages. So it usually better to install the latest version of the package you want to use and not to rely on one package to install others.

### npm link

Note that if you access to `x` via symlink, the `n` and other dependencies of `x` will not be installed.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Please allow me to clarify one more thing. If we use Webpack which bundling dependencies to output files, technically we can declare them in `devDependencies`, not `dependencies` of `package.json`, can not we? Because copyright comments has not being deleted by Webpack, it even will not be the MIT violation.

Comment: @TakesiTokugawaYD well, if you commit your bundle files to the library you're creating than yes, you don't need dependencies, but don't do it. It will make your library a waste because if will load tons of code again for no reason

Comment: Got it! Thank you again.

Comment: I improved your answer. Please correct me if I'm wrong.